# static_assert not working in Visual C++ 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, static-assert

I was under impression [Visual C++ 10 had built-in `static_assert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd293588.aspx). However when I compile the following

```
void test()
{
    static_assert( sizeof( char ) == 1, "" );
}
```

I get

> error C3861: 'static_assert': identifier not found

What am I doing wrong and how do I use `static_assert` in Visual C++ 10?

Comment: Maybe incorrect pack of VS10?

Comment: This compiles as expected in VS2010, SP1.

Comment: Maybe your toolset in the general preferences is wrong and points to an older compiler, because I am not aware of a compiler switch to disable c++0x.

Comment: Can you reproduce this error in a completely new project with just this line inside `main()` ?

Comment: @Nubcase: Yes, that's how I reproduce it - I create a "Win32 console project" and it is reproduced.

Comment: Are you by any chance compiling this as C instead of C++?

Comment: @Bo Persson: No, I tried both "default" and "C++" - the result is the same.

Comment: Then take the general help - reinstall VS. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was Visual Studio was set up to use Visual C++ 9 compiler (the one which is shipped with Visual Studio 2008). I don't know how it happened, perhaps the wizard configuring Visual Studio imported paths to the previous version.

The settings is changed in project properties - on "VC++ Directories" pane. The easy way to check which compiler is invoked is to add `-Bv` option to the compiler command line which will make the compiler report its version.

Answer (score 2):

> I was under impression Visual C++ 10 had built-in static_assert.

It indeed does and this compiles perfectly fine for me:

```
int main(){
    static_assert( sizeof( char ) == 1, "" );
}
```

Do you have any other errors in your code? Maybe this error is a result of the chain of other erros.

Comment: It might be related to the compilation flags... `static_assert` is a c++0x feature that is maybe disabled through options?

Comment: @David: Afaik there are no options to disable C++0x support in VC10 and even disabling language extensions (`/Za`) doesn't produce the error.